# Probability with bullets and walls

Tags: probability, combinatorics, normal-distribution, convolution

There are two shooters with different guns and bullets. Each shooter shoots a bullet to a different target hanging on a wall. The hit of each bullet follows a normal distribution centered on its target. Each bullet removes a piece of the wall whose volume follows a normal distribution centered on ten times the volume of the bullet.

What is the probabilty that a volume $V_1$ was extracted in a point $X_1$ on the wall by the shooters (*i.e.*, $P(V_1,X_1)$)?

What happens if we study two different points (*i.e.*, $P(V_1, X_1 \ and \ V_2, X_2)$)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your distributions are continuous *densities*, gaussian in this case, the probability of any point is 0. That is the answer to your questions as stated.

To get probabilities, you need to specify a region on $P(V_1,X_1)$ whose area is greater than zero. For example, lets say you want to know $P(V_1\pm\Delta V,X_1\pm\Delta X)$ Where $\Delta X, \Delta V >0$. What you want is the probability that either the bullet from shooter 1 or shooter 2 or both hit a location within $X\pm\Delta X$ and remove $V\pm\Delta V$ volume.

Let X be the modpoint of the interval where the wall will be hit by a bullet, and V be the midpoint of the volume interval for the piece removed. $B_i$ be the X-coordinate of bullet $i = 1,2$ $\mu_i$ be the X-coordinate of target $i$, $\sigma_{bi}$ be the standard deviation of the location of $B_i$,and $\sigma_{vi}$ the standard deviation of the volume removed. Then you need to get the probability for the folowing three situations:

(1) $P(|B_1-X|\leq\Delta X\cap|B_2-X|>\Delta X\cap |V_1-V|\leq \Delta V)$

(2) $P(|B_2-X|\leq\Delta X\cap|B_1-X|>\Delta X\cap |V_2-V|\leq \Delta V)$

(3) $P(|B_1-X|\leq\Delta X\cap|B_2-X|\leq\Delta X\cap |V_1+V_2-V|\leq \Delta V)$

You can now calculate each using the normal CDF function.